# Accessing SMS settings

Tags: android, sms

How to open `SMS` settings through my android application?

```
String SMS_MIME_TYPE = "vnd.android-dir/mms-sms";
Intent defineIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);                
defineIntent.setType(SMS_MIME_TYPE);
```

Comment: Why do you wan to do that?

Comment: is there any way to get Message setting? i want to just open sms settings window programaticaly

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by message setting ? Like input methods ?
Are you looking for this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS));
```

Check the possibilities of all the settings pages you can open here: [developer.android.com settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html)

Comment: This opens the language and keyboard settings. i want to open inbox message settings: where Delivery Reports, Notifications Vibration etc.